# jQuery glDatePicker plugin not rendering correctly on IE

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I'm using the [glDatePicker plugin](http://glad.github.io/glDatePicker).

Page loads, calendar is hidden (along w/ the box on it's right). `switch-view` is clicked, calendar is re-rendered and displayed. `Chrome, FF, Safari`, all is OK. `IE`, not so much. It looks as though when the calendar is rendered, the `width` is not being applied as it should.

***Chrome***

```
element.style {
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 382px;
  top: 259px;
  left: 766.5px;
  display: block;
```

***IE***

[image]

If I change the width to `382px` on `IE`, it displays as it should.

```
<article id="events" class="clearfix hidden-xs">
    <header class="clearfix header-title">
        <h2 class="row col-sm-8">Upcoming Events</h2>
        <a href="/resource-center/calendar-of-events" class="arrow-link gray-medium col-sm-4">All Events <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></a>
    </header>
    <div class="row">
        <section class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div id="calendar"></div>
        </section>
        <aside id="event-description" class="col-md-6  col-sm-6 gray-light">
            <img src="/content/images/events-backsplash.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            <div id="event-data">
                ....HTML here - not relevant
            </div>
        </aside>
    </div>
</article>

$('#switch-view').click(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('list-view')) {
        $('#event-description').hide();

        var $cal = $('#calendar').glDatePicker(true);
        $.extend($cal.options, {
            showAlways: false
        });

        $cal.render();
        $cal.hide();

        $('#calendar-list').fadeIn();
        $this.removeClass('list-view').find('span').text('Calendar View');
    }
    else {
        $this.addClass('list-view').find('span').text('List View');
        $('#calendar-list').hide();
        $('#event-description').fadeIn(function () {
            var $cal = $('#calendar').glDatePicker(true);
            $.extend($cal.options, {
                showAlways: true
            });

            $cal.render();
            $cal.show();
        });
    }

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I found that I had to `extend` the options and change the `showAlways` property to correctly hide/show on `IE`. If I remove those, then the calendar never hides when calling the `$cal.hide()` function.

You would think that I could just `hide` the `#calendar`, or it's container, but the way this plugin operates is it created a whole new `<div>` right before the ending `<body>` tag and does its "position magic".

[image: Chrome]

[image]

Comment: did u try that: http://www.objectpartners.com/2012/06/18/jquery-ui-datepicker-ie-focus-fix/   ?

Comment: ...this is not jquery-ui-datepicker

Comment: my bad, i try now create fiddle and solve it

Comment: cant repeat it in fiddle cos of libraries, can u send example? Hard to solve without examples

Comment: creating fiddle right now

Comment: it's not rendering in jsfiddle =\

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73431/discussion-between-legendary-and-rob-scott).

Answer (score 0):

Probably not THE answer to the question on as to WHY it was doing it, but somehow `IE 11` only was not gathering the `outerWidth()` and `offSet()` methods properly on `page load`.

What I ended up doing is determining if the browser was in fact `IE 11` and then setting a `timeout` of `1000ms` before the initial setup for the calendar.

If anyone has a better answer I'd love to hear it.

Apprec!